# Apache unset or trim cookie if value exceeds certain length

Tags: apache, cookies

There is a need to cut cookie or unset it if length exceeds certain character limit before it is processed by other modules. I could not find any solutions except modsecurity which has only option to block request.Is it even possible to determine length of a header or cookie value in Apache ?

Comment: The obvious candidate is [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_headers.html). The examples show you can combine it with `mod_setenvif` to do conditional stuff.

Comment: I could not find any example or documentation regarding cookie length check with mod_headers

Comment: Well, [mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_setenvif.html) has `SetEnvIf`, which accepts a regular expression. You could test the cookie against e.g. `.{200}` to find values larger than 200 characters, set an ENV variable and do stuff with `mod_headers` if the variable exists. I can't tell you the exact details (thus I left a comment rather than an answer).

Comment: I will look into this. Thanks